# Calculating the level of insertion based on the size of the tree

Tags: math, data-structures, graph, language-agnostic, tree

If I have a graph structure that looks like the following

```
a         level-1 
b c       level-2
c d e     level-3
e f g h   level-4
......    level-n

a points to b and c 
b points to c and d 
c points to d and e 
and so on
```

how can i calculate the n from the size(number of existing nodes) of the graph/tree?

Comment: I have removed the language tags since none seem relevant to your question. If one of them was appropriate after all, please specify how so we can give targetted information.

Comment: Are you looking for the height?

Comment: @turbo yes, i guess you can say that

Comment: Are you assuming the tree is optimally balanced?

Comment: Also, parent elements of a tree don't typically share a child; but that's what you describe.  Are you sure your example is correct?

Comment: i didn't mention a tree, i said graph

Comment: @nightograph Apologies then... the title, one of the tags, and the last line of your question lead me to conclude you were talking about trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of nodes present if the height is h is given by

> 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + h = h(h + 1) / 2

This means that one simple option would be to take the total number of nodes n and do a simple binary search to find the right value of h that such that h(h + 1) / 2 = n.

Alternatively, since n = h(h + 1) / 2, you can note that

> n = h(h + 1) / 2
>
> 2n = h<sup>2</sup> + h
>
> 0 = h<sup>2</sup> + h - 2n

Now you have a quadratic equation (in h) that you can solve to directly get back the value of h. The solution is

> h = (-1 ± √(1 + 8n)) / 2

If you take the minus branch, you'll get back a negative number, so you should take the positive branch and compute

> (-1 + √(1 + 8n)) / 2

to directly get back h.

Hope this helps!